# Attach a parameter in webview url

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm converting a webapp built on Laravel to a webview app with React Native.
Now, I would like to pass a parameter of ?utm-source=app on every URL.

What I've to do is check the Weview URL everytime before a load and check if URL already has a parameter like: website.com/new?latest=true. In such case I need to add "&utm-source=app" but if there is no any parameter, I need to attach "?utm-source=app" at the end of URL and load it on Webview.

Currently I've something like this:

```
...
 state = {
        URL: "domain.com"
    }
......
......

  <WebView source={{ uri: uri: this.state.url }} />
```

How can I achieve it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example showing how to achieve something like this:

```
function appendUtm(original) {
  if (original.indexOf("?") == -1) {
    return original + "?utm-source=app"
  } else {
    return original + "&utm-source=app"
  }
}
```

You can just send `appendUtm(this.state.URL)` to the `WebView`.

There could be cases that this doesn't cover, but it works with the basic examples you gave.  A more robust solution would also look for a pre-existing `utm-source` parameter and replace it, for example.

Note that in your sample code, you have capitalized `URL` in your `state {}` but lowercase `url` in the `WebView` parameter (which also looks like it has an extra `uri`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comments. The issue is that if I just browses URL other than homepage, the this.state.url is going to remain same. Is there anyway we could do appendUtm for any Webview source URL? For example, if a user goes from a homepage to a domain.com/story/1234 we no longer have that in our state so we can't append utm-source. What would be the solution? Is there an API available for Webview where we can manipulate URL before requesting? Thanks

Comment: Ah -- I see. Sorry, I didn't get that from the initial question.  `WebView` (assuming `react-native-webview`) has an `onNavigationStateChange` parameter/callback you can use for this.  You'll need a `ref` to use it.  There's a full code example at https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#controlling-navigation-state-changes